# Django rest "this field is requiered" on a many to many field when blank=True

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an object I would like to be able to make via django-rest-api UI. 
This object has a manytomany field that holds other objects on it.

Even though that field is blank param is set to True, I get a response that "this field is requiered".

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    content = HTMLField('Content', null=True)
    black_listed = models.ManyToManyField('profile_app.Profile', related_name='black_listed_posts', blank=True)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

serializers.py:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    black_listed = ProfileSerializer(many=True)
    read_only = ('id',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        self.black_listed = []

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'slug', 'description',
                  'content',
                  'black_listed', 'score')
```

views.py:

```
class PostViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "slug"

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.black_listed = []
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

As you can see, i tried overriding the `create()` method on both serializer and viewset, but that didnt work and still gave me that the black_list field is requiered.

[image]

What i expected that if the field is not required in the db, then the serializer can set it to None on the creation

what am i missing here?

EDIT:

ProfileSerializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interests = InterestSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('slug', 'user_id', 'image', 'role', 'work_at', 'interests')
```

Comment: can you show up the `ProfileSerializer`?

Comment: added in edit..

Comment: Try adding `required=False` and `allow_null=True` on `black_listed = ProfileSerializer(many=True, required=False, allow_null=True)`

Comment: Awesome! you can put it in an answer for others to be able to see - i will except it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide the [`required=False`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects) argument in your serializer declaration:

```
class PostSerializer(...):
    black_listed = ProfileSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    # __________________________________________^
```

If you want to be able to post *null values* for this field, you may also add [`allow_null=True`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#inspecting-a-modelserializer).